# how can i make a frontend login that will never expire in magento?

Tags: magento, authentication

I want to make a login on the frontend of magento, that doesn't depend on a session, because I don't want it to expire, ever.
Probably this will go with cookies, but how?
If I use sessions, it will expire when the browser closes

Answer (score 2):

In PHP sessions are based on cookies. Session identifier is stored in user's cookie. You can't set a session to live forever but you can set it for a very long period (for example for 1 year). You can adjust cookie life time in Magento admin area (System->General->Web->Session Cookie Management->Cookie Lifetime). You should set a value in seconds, so for 1 year it will be 31536000. But you should keep in mind that it will get some amount of space too keep sessions and also if you store session in filesystem you shouldn't delete folder var/session or you'll loose all users sessions.

Comment: Patrik ,also try to used persistent cache in login